# Python でモジュール内変数の謎な動き

Tags: python, python3

module内変数にアクセスするな、というお叱りの言葉を受けそうですが、main.pyでaを100にする方法はないのでしょうか？

```
# main.py
from sub import *
foo()
print(a) # 0が表示される T-T)/
```

```
# sub.py
a = 0
def foo():
    global a
    a = 100
```

また、不思議なのは、以下のようにすると100が表示されることです。

```
# main.py
from sub import *
baa() # 100が表示される
```

```
# sub.py
a = 0
def foo():
    global a
    a = 100
def baa():
    print(a)
```

T^T)/ よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 2つ目の`main.py`は`baa()`の前に`foo()`が抜けていますね。

Answer (score 1):

この記事の回答やPythonのドキュメントが参考になるでしょう。この記事自体の`import`とグローバル変数が何処に定義されているかは今の質問とは違いますが。
その回答の中で、3つのパターンの対処が説明されています。
[Visibility of global variables in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15959534/9014308)

> Globals in Python are global to a module, not across all modules. (Many people are confused by this, because in, say, C, a global is the same across all implementation files unless you explicitly make it `static`.)

> PythonのGlobalsは、すべてのモジュールにまたがるわけではなく、(個々の)モジュールに対してglobalです。 （たとえば、C(言語)では、明示的に`static`にしない限り、globalはすべての実装ファイルで同じであるため、多くの人がこれに混乱しています。）

つまり`main.py`で`sub.py`を`import`してアクセス出来る`a`と、`sub.py`の中からアクセスできる`a`は違う物だということです。

---

同様のことは以下のPythonのドキュメントにも記述されています。

[グローバル変数をモジュール間で共有するにはどうしたらいいですか？](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)

> 一つのプログラムのモジュール間で情報を共有する正準な方法は、特別なモジュール (しばしば config や cfg と呼ばれる) を作ることです。単に設定モジュールをアプリケーションのすべてのモジュールにインポートしてください。

そして両方の記事とも、`モジュール名.`を変数の頭に付けてアクセスするよう説明されています。